# Phoenix Contact PLC software assembled with which language?

Tags: plc

I am having hard time to find assembled codes of programmes i have written in Structured Text and Instruction List languages. I can't find binary code of written codes and dont know in which ISA they are converted. I got a write a disassembler for those binary codes.

Comment: It isn't clear what you want.  OK, you've written a program in ST.  Presumably in the context of a particular manufacturer's PLC, and according to his rules for software development and any IDE support he has provided. That support compiles the ST for execution on the target platform.   You can't find the output of the compiler? YOu don't know the ISA of your PLC? (The manufacturer is under no obligation to tell you, but this fact isn't usually hard to determine).   Why do you have to write a disassembler?

Comment: The next step is the parallelization and optimization that I dont know much about. My friend did the same thing with Siemens device. And in the project file there was a db file holds binaries for the codes. He found it and he made his disassembler by examining Siemens ISA for the devices.

Comment: You don't know much about your PLC, and you are contemplating "parallelization" and (generated code) "optimization"?  Using a dissembler as a starting place?  I think you don't know what you are proposing.  Given that you don't know what the ISA is, how do you know if your PLC can run anything in parallel, let alone how?   If you did know, you'd get these effects by modifying the compiler, which I doubt you have access to.  ....

Comment: ... as with many questions of the form of "I like to do <obscure thing X> to achieve <obscure goal G>", you might be better off asking a question related to your real goal.  "My PLC programs on Phoenix controllers runs too slowly.  What can I can do to improve their performance?"

Comment: yea thats the thing. I dont know much about PLC (Thats why I am responsible from "disassembling" part) and I cant find anything on Device Manuals or on tutorials about PLC s.

Comment: I don't think you read what I wrote carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As Ira has said, I think your approach is rather misguided.  There really isn't anything much to disassemble as far as PLC instructions go. PLC instructions (ladder, IL, etc) are lightly, if at all, abstracted from direct machine instructions to begin with.  When you are looking at an IL, you are essentially looking at a form of assembly language.

If execution time is a problem then there is little you could do to optimize them at a machine level - you're already working there.  The algorithms themselves are what need to change.  Every PLC manual will list execution times for every instruction it supports - this is where you should start your search to optimize.  Have a look over the program and try to identify which rungs are eating up your scan time.  Floating point operations, especially, and loops (which you shouldn't be using anyway!) are places where you can really rack up execution time.  See if there aren't ways for you to refactor there.  Can you change divisions to multiplications, etc?

The other possibility may simply be that the PLC you are working with is not suitable for the job.  Most manufacturers offer a range of base units at a range of prices.  Execution speed between these systems can vary dramatically.  I have a series of low-cost PLC units, for example, in the very same family of units, the fastest of which (DL450) can execute a binary divide in 23 microseconds and the slowest of which (DL430) will take nearly 5000 microseconds.  The DL450 will execute its entire (rather complex) scan in less time than it takes the DL430 to perform two divisions!  I have several Omron PLCs which will complete their entire program scan in the time of ONE DL430 division.

Do you maybe just need a faster base unit?